# JQuery closeable tabs and Ajax scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I have following closeable JQuery tabs running on my page. It opens a new jsp page in the tab which is running an ajax function to poll latest data (through a servlet). The HREF link contains the parameters based on which polling occurs. While the first page opens fine, additional pages do not run the script except the first one. Any ideas?

Tried setting cache true (first page works fine and all the time) and false (the first page also stops working on opening a new tab)

JQuery in the main page :

```
function opentabs() {
    $(function () {
        var tab_counter = 0;
        $('#tabs1').tabs({
            closable: true,
            cache: false,
            add: function (e, ui) {
                $('#tabs1').tabs('select', '#' + ui.panel.id);
            }
        });
        $("a.tablinks").bind("click", function () {
            tab_counter += 1;
            $('#tabs1').tabs('add', $(this).attr('href'), $(this).attr('id'));
            return false;
        });
        $('#tabs2').tabs();
    });
}(jQuery);

$(document).ready(opentabs);
```

Ajax polling function in the linked jsp page:

```
var i=self.setInterval("sendRequest()",60000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure that I understand all your problem, but looking at the code itself, I see this:

The `$(document).ready` is called only once, when the page is loaded. Thus, it's not called again when a new tab is loaded.

Comment: Thanks for your reply FMaz. The closeable tabs JQuery runs in the main page and works fine. The tabs are a link to another jsp page, which runs a polling ajax to query latest data in each of the tabs. First tab works fine (i.e) the linked jsp page keeps polling the latest data (its like a dashboard with running meters). Every new tab opened after that doesn't run the polling ajax function.

Comment: But what trigger/call that polling ajax function? and when does that occur ?

Comment: The ajax function is triggered by var i=self.setInterval(sendRequest(), 60000) script on the page. And unloaded with <body onunload="window.clearInterval(i)"> to stop the polling.

Each tab is supposed to show periodically updated meter readings from specific site. Like tab 1 for site 1 and tab 2 for site 2 etc.